# Spring's Java based Config project display 404

Tags: java, spring

I recently created Spring maven project, and I am using pure java based configuration,and on running the same, I encountered 404. I am clueless here.

**AppInitializer (web.xml replacement)**

```
package com.mzk.mascot.configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

/**
 *
 * @author Ossu
 */
public class WebApplicationBootstrapper implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        applicationContext.register(SpringBeanContainer.class);
        dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherServletConfiguration.class);

        ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener=new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext);
        sc.addListener(contextLoaderListener);

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

**Spring bean container (app-context.xml replacement)**

```
package com.mzk.mascot.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

/**
 *
 * @author Ossu
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.mzk.mascot.controller"})
public class SpringBeanContainer {

}
```

**Finally Dispatcher-servlet config file**

```
package com.mzk.mascot.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 *
 * @author Ossu
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.mzk.mascot.controller"})
public class DispatcherServletConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        ResourceHandlerRegistration handlerRegistration = registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**");
        handlerRegistration.addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

}
```

Before this configuration, it by default render the `index.html` by accessing **`http://localhost:8084/Mascot/`**. After adding these three classes, it displays 404, I still not able to figure it out, kindly help me if I am wrong at any place on in any class, please tell me and correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to update the `DispatcherServletConfiguration` class.

At first update `addResourceHandlers()` method and register static HTML pages handler:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/");
}
```

Then override `addViewControllers()` method where is forwarding from */* (root) to */index.html*:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
```

And at the end move *index.html* file into *WEB-INF/static* folder.

**Note:** If your *index.html* page is only redirecting somewhere else (on */welcome* for example) then you can do the forward directly:

```
registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/welcome");
```

Comment: thanx dude, will surely implement your suggestion and notify you if work for me :)

Comment: Thank yuo bro, but still i am stuck, i implemented the same, but not able to get rid of 404

Comment: I used the same classes as you have in the question and it works. What version of Spring do you use?

Comment: Hey, it worked :), but only if i moved the html page inside the view, and yes,by the way, what is the root cause, are you able to figure it out??

Comment: Why it renders html page, it not able to render jsp, I changed all the string to handle .jsp files

Comment: What happens when you try http://localhost:8084/Mascot/index.html ?
Do you have this line `registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/");` in `addResourceHandlers()` method? Is _index.html_ in _/WEB-INF/static_ folder?

Comment: No, html worked, but not jsp, when I moved the same inside view (static folder in my case)

Comment: `registry.addResourceHandler("*/*.jsp").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/view/");`

Comment: In case of html, it is working fine, but in case of jsp, it is not working as per  expectation

Comment: @user9634982 How to handle JSPs is defined in `viewResolver()` and you have it correct (in the question).
But registering JSP in `addResourceHandlers()` method as a resource makes no sense. Remove this line: `registry.addResourceHandler("*/*.jsp").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/view/");`

Comment: ya  i commented the same, but jsp is not rendered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182038/discussion-between-user9634982-and-cgrim).